# Is Home Roasting / Home Brewing of Coffee within scope?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Wondering if the "Homebrewing" moniker stretches to include home brewing of coffee (and more interestingly home roasting of coffee)

I see similarities in roasting malts and roasting coffee. I do both (roast / brew coffee and brew beer, and make wine for that matter ;) ) and would love to ask some coffee specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a coffee proposal but it was closed as a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com

(only visible to area 51 mods but for completeness -- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4501/coffee )

You might try asking your coffee related questions there.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I think I committed to the coffee proposal, bummed to see it closed. I will try cooking and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

LOL, that's a bit of a pun, isn't it? :D

Comment: I am always proud to deliver a good pun but in this case I actually am serious (and I am missing the pun....?)

Comment: Well...I think it's pretty clear that this isn't a site that has anything to do with coffee, but with brewing alcohol and wine. The process of making those products and the process of making coffee are both called by the same name, but don't actually have much of anything in common. It's a pun in that the word means two different things.